# Spark-submit on Yarn errors YarnConfiguration.useHttps NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a spark-submit on yarn and I get below error. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration.useHttps(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Z)
16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
16/07/05 14:21:49 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle I figured out, the issue was I was building the uber jar with all dependencies which include spark as well. When I build package without dependencies and dependent jars were added as --jars during spark submit the issue was resolved. It seems most of the times issues like NoSuchMethodError or ClassNotFoundException can be resolved with this approach.